# Microsoft JScript bypassing certificate error

Tags: jscript, winhttp

I am trying to bypass the message *"The certificate authority is invalid or incorrect"* for a WinHTTP request. I read that this can be achieved by [WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384066.aspx) function.

- How do I set this?
- More importantly, is this valid for Microsoft JScript?

I have an object handler that catches the certificate message but I want to bypass the certificate message and reprocess the request.

Answer (score 0):

This helped resolve it

```
WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString            = 0;
WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags        = 4;
WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects            = 6;
WinHttpRequestOption_EnableHttpsToHttpRedirects = 12;

SslErrorFlag_Ignore_All = 0x00003300;

WinHttpReq.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_UserAgentString)            = "http_requester/0.1";
WinHttpReq.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_SslErrorIgnoreFlags)        = SslErrorFlag_Ignore_All ;
WinHttpReq.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects)            = "True";
WinHttpReq.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableHttpsToHttpRedirects) = "True";
```